# react Library UseForm was used. help me see the input image in advance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made input used `{useform} library`.
It was appropriate to use many "input".

However, the image preview "Enter" does not work.
I tried to preview the image. I hope you get help.

`background-image: url(null); It's printed.`

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from 'react-select';


const SingleInput = () => {
return(
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null);

  const saveFileImage = event => {
    const imageFile = event.target.files[0];
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
    setFileUrl(imageUrl);
  };

  <label>
    add Media
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={saveFileImage}
      accept="image/*"
      {...register('file')}
    />
  </label>
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${fileUrl})`,
    }}
  />

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your `onChange` method on input is overrided by `onChange` from `register()`. Try to get data from useForm itself or wrap input in Controller, so you can customize this behaviour.